# Toshiba satellite radius not loading bootable usb

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, bootloader, toshiba-satellite

I recently bought a Toshiba satellite radius (model: L15W-B1120). I already read countless of posts. In the posts they recommend to disable secure boot and also fastboot, I already did.

I created a recovery bootable usb for windows (just in case) and the bootable usb to install ubuntu. When I'm booting the computer I select to boot from the USB  and when I try with the ubuntu bootable usb it doesn't work, nonetheless, if I'm using the recovery usb for windows it works. I'm creating the bootable with Unetbootin, it always works with my other computers, but not with this one apparently. Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: What Ubuntu distribution do you use? How did you write the bootable usb?

Comment: It isn't a USB3, is it? There are a few problems with that standard when it comes to booting.

Comment: @pilot6 ubuntu 14.04,, i wrote it with unetbootin

Comment: @Fiximan, it's usb 2

Comment: Is it 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: 64 bit, but nonetheless, it should at least run the first part of the booting, but apparently it just doesn't want to run the bootable usb of ubuntu, while the bootalbe usb of the windows recovery is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed UbuntuGNOME 15.04 just recently and v608 of Unetbootin for windows consistently failed to write a bootable image.I solved the problem by using `imageusb` to burn the iso on to the drive. You should also see the checksum of the .iso that could tell you if it's a corrupted download. 
To do that in windows if you have 8 or 8.1 is to open powershell cd to the directory and type

```
Get-FileHash -Algorithm sha256/md5/etc .\thefileyouwanttocheck.iso
```

It's slow for bigger files it may well take up to a minute or more, so don't close it.Otherwise you'll need to download a tool for checksums.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, usually I use unetbootin with linux, but it's true that this time I installed it with windows. Thanks ;)

Comment: I hope it helps.

Comment: you got it right, such a basic error, but this time I didn't have another computer to verify it first. Thanks men ;)

Answer (score 0):

Fast boot option will be there in **BIOS**. You have to turn off that feature. Then select USB as boot device.

Try any of these steps to get in to the **BIOS**. Either of these might work.

- To reach the **BIOS** when fast-boot is turned on, you should hold down the F2 key and then power-on the computer.

***OR***

- Power on and press escape key for 3 seconds, A **BIOS** key will be prompt at bottom of your screen. Sometimes it will be F2 key or DEL key.

***OR***

- Power on and press escape key for 3 seconds. F12 will lead to boot menu. Then select USB as boot device.

Comment: I already turned off, still not booting the usb, any thoughts?

Comment: Confirm whether the mode is CSM in "advanced- system configuration -boot mode" in **BIOS**.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest BIOS from Toshiba. Version 5 was released July 2015, disable secure boot, disable fast boot in Windows 10.

I have the same Toshiba Satellite series, and had the exact same issue, I had to reinstall grub every time I had a hard lockup/freeze. Some reason it doesn't want to save the EFI boot loader properly or it was being corrupted in the hard freeze. Upgrading the BIOS fixed the issue for me.

And these devices have two USB ports, the USB-2.0 port is on the right side of the system when looking directly at the screen. and the USB-3.0 port is on the left side of the device.

The easiest way to tell in most cases where a USB port is 2.0 or 3.0 is the color of the plastic inside the port. USB-3.0 is blue (this won't be true in 100% of instances, because some manufacturers ignore standards, but in the instance of this laptop, the left USB port is 3.0).

A problem I have been having since day one is hard freezes on these devices almost seemingly at random. I narrowed it down to Toshiba improperly reporting its acpi information properly to the Linux kernel, but seems to provide a Microsoft OS with everything it needs. This issue is caused by Linux unable to address/locate the internal cooling fan, and the only work around I have found that seems to reduce the freezes/hard locks, is to use tlp, tlp-stat, lm-sensors, sensor, psensor and thermald to set temperature triggers to throttle CPU clock frequency to keep it from going above 60 deg C. (just a heads up after you solve your boot loader issue)